# Is there a way to do a crosshair staying fixed on Y axis of the player (2d upper view) and moving on that Y axis as distant as mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a spaceships game with my other friends with Unity using c# programmation. Our game is 2d with a vision of the player from the up. We need to do 2 crosshairs: one that is the replacement of the mouse cursor (done) and the spaceship y axis follow mouse cursor so the spaceship rotate following the mouse cursor crosshair with a delay. In this delay time, the spaceship doesn't aim exactly at mouse crosshair because the rotation is not immediately so we  want to do a second crosshair that follow Y axis of the spaceship to make the player understand when the ship's armaments will target the cursor position exactly. This second crosshair must scroll along the y-axis of the ship so that the distance between the ship and the mouse cursor is the same between the secondary viewfinder in the Y axis.
Here you can find an exemple of the game: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATTcZ.jpg

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseCursor : MonoBehaviour{

public Texture2D cursorTexture;
public Transform aim;
public float aimSpeed = 3.0f;
private Vector2 cursorHotspot;
private Vector2 aim2;
private Vector3 mouseP;
private Vector2 direction;
// initialize mouse with a new texture with the
// hotspot set to the middle of the texture
// (don't forget to set the texture in the inspector
// in the editor)
void Start()
{
    cursorHotspot = new Vector2(cursorTexture.width / 2, cursorTexture.height / 2);
    Cursor.SetCursor(cursorTexture, cursorHotspot, CursorMode.Auto);
}

// To check where your mouse is really pointing
// track the mouse position in you update function
void Update()
{
    //from this the second crosshair code
    Vector3 currentMouse = Input.mousePosition;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(currentMouse);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);
    Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point);

    var dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

    aim2 = new Vector2(dir.x , dir.y);

    aim.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, aim2, aimSpeed);


}
}
```

Actually the second crosshair remain in Y axis as excepted but he won't move as distant as the mouse cursor from the ship so both the crosshair will not completely align one above the other.

Answer (score -1):

put the AIM in the player,then AIM take the player rotation and thats a base of the code AIM

'''C#

```
public Transform aim;//AIM position "aim image"
public float aimSpeed;//speed AIM
public float zonaMorta;//death zone value where the AIM can't move

private Vector3 target;//position where the AIM need to go
private Vector3 posAim;//AIM position

void Update ()
    {
        float pr = transform.rotation.z;//take the rotation value from the player
        float ty = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y;//y axis value of the mouse.
        target = new Vector3(0 , ty, 0);//allowance the y axis of the cursor to "target"
        posAim = aim.transform.position;//allowance AIM position to "posAim"
        posAim = new Vector3(0, posAim.y, 0);//on posAim I keep only y while x, z gate them

        if(posAim.y + zonaMorta > target.y && posAim.y - zonaMorta < target.y)//if AIM is between this two value then it can't move, it can't move in the y axis
    {

    }else{

        if(pr > -90f || pr < 90f){//if the rotation of the player is more than -90 degrees or less than 90 degrees then ..
            if(posAim.y > target.y)//if y axis of AIM is greater than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                aim.transform.position -= aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//subtract and allowance at the AIM position a positive velocity in the y axis
            }
            if(posAim.y < target.y)//if y axis of AIM is lesser than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                    aim.transform.position += aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//sum and allowance at the AIM position a positive velocity in the y axis
                }                   
                }
      if(pr < -90f || pr > 90f){//if the rotation of the player is less than -90 degrees or more than 90 degrees then ..

            if(posAim.y > target.y)//if y axis of AIM is greater than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                aim.transform.position -= -aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//subtract and allowance at the AIM position a negative velocity in the y axis
            }
            if(posAim.y < target.y)//if y axis of AIM is lesser than the y axis of the cursor then..
            {
                    aim.transform.position += -aim.transform.up * aimSpeed;//sum and allowance at the AIM position a negative velocity in the y axis
                }                   
                }
            }
        }
```

'''

Comment: Can you add text to your response? That is, guide your answer with text outside of code comments/code snippets and clearly explain what you've done with your code.

Comment: This method works "a bit" because the second crosshair will Never stop when it reachs the mouse position so the crosshair goes up and down infinitely. Do you have another idea or Fix for it? Wots Herflux is coworking with me for the project and answered this post because he tought he solved the problem but this method wont work properly